Why am I getting an error when I pull a fetchDir function?
I have written this piece of code where I listen to a function in the frontend and then pull 2 function when it is called here are the 2 functions.
Here is where we listen to the frontend:
    socket.on("fetchStartUpProjects", async (data) => {
        console.log("Fetch Function Recieved",data)
        await fetchS3Folder(`code/${data}`, path.join(__dirname, `../tmp/${data}`));
        socket.emit("loaded", {
            rootContent: await fetchDir(path.join(__dirname, `../tmp/${data}`), "")
        }
    );
        // console.log("success", fetchDir(path.join(__dirname, `../tmp/${data}`), "") )
        // initHandlers(socket, data);
    });
})


This is the fetchS3Folder where I fetch the folders from an S3 Dir:
const fetchS3Folder = async (key, localPath) => {
    try {
        const params = {
            Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET || "",
            Prefix: key
        };

        const response = await s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise();
        if (response.Contents) {
            // Use Promise.all to run getObject operations in parallel
            await Promise.all(response.Contents.map(async (file) => {
                const fileKey = file.Key;
                if (fileKey) {
                    const getObjectParams = {
                        Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET || "",
                        Key: fileKey
                    };

                    const data = await s3.getObject(getObjectParams).promise();
                    if (data.Body) {
                        const fileData = data.Body;
                        const filePath = `${localPath}/${fileKey.replace(key, "")}`;
                        
                        await writeFile(filePath, fileData);

                        console.log(`Downloaded ${fileKey} to ${filePath}`);
                    }
                }
            }));
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching folder:', error);
    }
};

and this is the fetchDir function that I made to store it into local storage.
How can I make it like S3 so that it automatically makes a folder when there isn't one?
Here is the fetchDir function that I am calling:
function fetchDir(dir, baseDir) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readdir(dir, { withFileTypes: true }, (err, files) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(files.map(file => ({
                    type: file.isDirectory() ? "dir" : "file",
                    name: file.name,
                    path: `${baseDir}/${file.name}`
                })));
            }
        });
    });
}

Here is the error I am getting:
Fetch Function Recieved coolopento
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'D:\Coding\VStart Main\tmp\coolopento'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: 'D:\\Coding\\VStart Main\\tmp\\coolopento'
}

Node.js v20.14.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

tried to code it myself but I couldnt as I am a beginner.
